# Quero por "" nos números do meu JSON

Tags: javascript, node.js

Tenho um *script* em `node.js` que pega o `json` de um site que vem nesse formato:

```
{"nome123":123.4,"nome213":231.4."nome123":123.4}
```

Quero por aspas nos números e deixar ele assim:

```
{"nome123":"123.4","nome213":"231.4","nome123":"123.4"}
```

Como faço isso?

```
const saPrices = `https://api.csgofast.com/sih/all`
Trade.prototype.getSteamapis = function getSteamapis(callback) {
  request(saPrices, (error, response, body) => {
    if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
        const items = JSON.parse(body)
        return callback(null, items)
    }
    const statusCode = (response) ? response.statusCode || false : false
    return callback({ error, statusCode })
})  
}
```

Comment: Olá Luciandro,
Bem vindo ao StackOvervflow pt. Tente incrementar mais sua pergunta com pedaço de código, para ajudar a comunidade a entender melhor a sua dúvida

Comment: Precisas mesmo de mudar esses numeros para Strings?

Comment: Todos os valores desse objeto são numeros? ou há outros valores de texto, arrays, etc?

Answer (score 3):

Em um objeto JSON, se um valor está entre aspas, isso é um indicativo de que se trata de uma `string`. Números propriamente ditos não são encapados por aspas.

Logo, se o que você deseja é que seus números sejam mesmo texto e não aspas, você pode transformá-los em texto no seu código.

Para transformar um número em texto em Javascript, existem duas formas. Supondo uma variável qualquer chamada `x`:

Forma mais elegante:

```
x = x.toString();
```

Forma mais curta:

```
x = x + "";
```

Por fim, você pode varrer o seu objeto JSON assim:

```
for (var x in json) {
    if (typeof json[x] === "number") {
        json[x] = json[x] + ""; // ou pode usar a forma elegante
    }
}
```